# What is Acer Liquid Metal maximum SD card speed class?

Tags: external-sd, performance

I want to buy a new sd and I'd like to get best bang (and speed) for the buck...
But I can't find this information...
Anybody knows?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe not all classes work?  Otherwise I don't think this is a real question.

Comment: I just don't know and I would not like to buy something that doesn't work well.
That's why I'm asking...

Comment: OK, I'll answer I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason a class 10 card wouldn't work.  The card being faster shouldn't break anything.  I can find no evidence that the Acer Liquid Metal detects and behaves badly with a fast card, or does not use the SD card specifications properly, or anything like that.

Comment: I just wanted to know if it was worth buying a class 25 device if my acer liquid metal supports maximum a class 4 :)

Comment: @Pitto Class 10 is the maximum.  If you want advice about which card to get, I'd get a good brand name (like Kingston) and you don't need more than a class 6.  Normal reads and writes shouldn't delay the system at that speed, and it should be fine for video recording.  Most phones ship with class 4, so that would probably work fine as well.

Comment: That was what I was looking for :)

Comment: I bought a class 6 SD and it works nice!